# How to pass extracted features to keras model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I extract the features of a series of images provided along with their labels from a csv file as

```
data = pandas.read_csv("data.csv", delimiter=',', dtype=str)
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    img = image.load_img(row['image_path'], target_size=(img_width, img_height))
    trainImage = image.img_to_array(img)
    trainImage = np.expand_dims(trainImage, axis=0)
```

How should I save the `trainImages` and `trainLabels` into the corresponding arrays during the above loop for passing to the model

```
trainLabels = np_utils.to_categorical(trainLabels, num_classes)
model.fit(trainImages, trainLabels, nb_epoch=3, batch_size=16)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# create lists to hold data
X_train, y_train = [], []

# while looping add feature vector and labels to X_train, y_train resp.
X_train.append(trainImage)
y_train.append(trainLabel)

# convert y_train to categorical

# pass to model
```